# Check if Range exist as substring in a cell (googlesheets)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Most formulas I already checked are about finding if a specific cell exists in a range.
I am trying to check the opposite, if values from a specific range exist as substring in a specific cell.

Example, my range A1:A10 is:

```
Juan Lopez
John Smith
Philip Sue
Philip Stark
Ronaldo Doe
```

And I want to check of any one of these values in the range exist in my cell C1

```
C1 = "Senior Designer: Philip Stark (France)"
```

the answer should be "Philip Stark"

What formula could I use for this?

Until now I have used :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$10,C1)))>0
```

This return true/false if value in range exists in target cell C1. But how can I get the Value from Range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return `TRUE` if any non-blank string from `A1:A10` is in `C1`:

`=REGEXMATCH(C1, JOIN("|", FILTER(A1:A10, A1:A10 <> "")))`

This will return a range of `TRUE`/`FALSE` for every string in `A1:A10` if it is in `C1` or not:

`=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(C1, A1:A10))`

And this one will return only strings in `A1:A10` which are in `C1`:

`=FILTER(A1:A10, REGEXMATCH(C1, A1:A10))`

Mind the special regex chars which should be escaped if they are in those `A1:A10` strings (there are none in your example, so I did not add this escaping).

Comment: this answer does not return the range value, only true/false

Comment: @BTC75 what range do you need? True/False for every string in `A1:A10`?

Comment: @BTC75 updated the answer. It is not clear what you need to achieve.

Comment: Instead of "true" i need the value to be returned : Philip Stark

Comment: @BTC75 what is this value? The 1st match? All the matches? Have you tried the 3rd solution I suggested?

Comment: =FILTER(A1:A10, REGEXMATCH(C1, A1:A10)) does the trick. Good!